# How to redirect a non www domain to WWW domain in asp.net mvc hosted on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis-7, web-config

I have set up ssl on [www.mydomain.tech](http://www.mydomain.tech) in Azure. (mydomain.tech is a sample url not my actual domain). When I enter the url [www.mydomain.tech](http://www.mydomain.tech) I don't get any errors because SSL is working fine. When I go to mydomain.tech directly I get DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID error. **I need to transfer any request which comes to mydomain.tech to [www.mydomain.tech](http://www.mydomain.tech)** I am using the below code in Web.Config file to transfer. It is not working. Is my Url Pattern wrong or do I need to make any other change in azure to reflect my Web.Config changes? Please suggest.
PS - I have restarted Azure machine after applying the change in Web.config.

```
<rule name="Redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">  
            <match url=".*"></match>  
            <conditions>  
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.tech$"></add>  
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"></add>  
            </conditions>  
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomain.tech/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"></action>  
        </rule>
```

Comment: Does your cert _also_ cover `mydomain.tech` (without the www)? If not, it needs to. Or the browser won't hit `mydomain.tech`.

Comment: No it does not cover without www. As mentioned above if I go to non www it simply gives a SSL warning that the connection is not secure. That is the reason I need any NON www to be redirected to WWW automatically. Hence the code above in Web.Config.

Comment: You need a non www cert. Then the redirect will work. You aren't getting to the redirect due to the lack of a cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a separate pfx file for both the domains using a free SSL provider(SSL for free) and had to add bindings for both the domains to make it work. Also had to enforce azure to use HTTPS only. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article by Ray: **[3 Ways to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.discountasp.net/3-ways-to-redirect-http-to-https-and-non-www-to-www-in-asp-net-core/)**

You might notice that you are missing below piece of code in `Startup.cs` file:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
   .AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "XML_FILE_NAME")
   .AddRedirectToHttps()
);
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can also try out any of the other two alternate methods.